# Printing Elements of a Java array

Tags: java, arrays

I made a board class that is simply an array with 3 integers.

```
public class board
{
   public int[] boardArray = new int [3];

   public board (int[] b1)
   {
      for(int i=0;i<b1.length;i++)
      {
         boardArray[i] = b1[i];
      }
   }

}
```

I want to print out all the boards added to an array list called losers, but I can only get it to print the spot in memory. I understand that I have to run a loop and call each individual piece of the array up, but I do not understand how to access the elements of my array. Here is the code I use to print:

```
for (board b : loser)
{
  System.out.println( b.int[0] +"" + b.int[1]+"" + b.int[2]);
}
```

Comment: Its `b.boardArray[0]` not `b.int[0]`.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that a [Java Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) is not the same thing as an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) - the latter is a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) *backed by* an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all the boards added to an array list called losers

```
for (board b : loser)
  {
  System.out.println( b.boardArray[0] +"" + b.boardArray[1]+"" + b.boardArray[2]);
  }
```

Since `boardArray` is an type  of`int` in `board` class. But `int` is an datatype not a variable. Just replace `b.int[index]` with `b.boardArray[index]`.

Answer (score 1):

This `System.out.println( b.int[0] +"" + b.int[1]+"" + b.int[2]);` should be something like

```
System.out.println( b.boardArray[0] +" " + b.boardArray[1]
        + " " + b.boardArray[2]);
```

**or** override `toString` in `board` (which by Java naming conventions, should start with a capital letter `Board`). Also, you might use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(boardArray);
}
```

then you could call `System.out.println(b);` Finally, an `int[]` (array of integers) is not an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) (a generic `List` implementation that is backed by, but distinct from, an array).

Answer (score 0):

your array name is `boardArray` of type int, so fields or variables are accessed by name not by type. replace `int` by `boardArray`

```
System.out.println( b.boardArray[0] +"" + b.boardArray[1]+"" + b.boardArray[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `b.boardArray[]` since boardArray is the member of board class. int is the datatype of boardArray, not a variable.

```
import java.util.*;

class board
{
   public int[] boardArray = new int [3];

   public board (int[] b1)
   {
      for(int i=0;i<b1.length;i++)
      {
         boardArray[i] = b1[i];
      }
   }

}

public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<board>loser=new ArrayList<>();

        int[] a1 = {10,20,30};
        int[] a2 = {80,90,91};

        loser.add(new board(a1));
        loser.add(new board(a2));

        for(board b : loser)
        {
            System.out.println( b.boardArray[0] +" " + b.boardArray[1]+" " + b.boardArray[2]);
        }
    }
}
```